# Javascript - Execute calls one AFTER another

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a piece of code where I must maintain the order. I have a date dropdown which is loaded by an ajax call. After the dropdown has been populated I call another function that selects one of the dates based on a condition. Based on that date I trigger onchange event and make another Ajax call which fetches times for a dropdown.

So Order matters and I must make sure that next call doesn't execute unless the current one has finished for sure. I tried traditional way of doing it like,

`callOne();`
`callTwo();`
`callThree();`

But i realized `callTwo();` doesn't get enough time to make changed to what `callOne();` did. But If I place an `alert();` between `callOne();` and `callTwo();` it works.

I tried to make use of `Promise`. But this below code doesn't go beyond first `log`

```
let prom = new Promise(function(){
            console.log('jgjgj')

            $("#id_session_type").on('change', load_dates).trigger('change');
        }).then(function(){

                console.log('1111')
                set_date_from_hidden();
            }).then(function(){

                $("#id_date").on('change', load_time_slots);
        }).then(function(){

            $("#id_time").on('change', set_hidden_time);
        });
```

Comment: Promise needs resolve and/or reject method to return when complete. Look up promise.

Comment: Attaching the event listeners does not need to happen in a particular sequence. What is relevant is the code *inside* those listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Promises chaining can make sure function called one by one.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve();
  console.log(1);

}).then(function(result) {

  console.log(2);

  return Promise.resolve();

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  console.log(3);

  return Promise.resolve();

}).then(function(result) {

  console.log(4);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know why someone downvoted you without any reason given. I upvoted you because I think this is almost similar to what worked for me. I would accept your answer because you posted it here first. But I need to know if `return Promise.resolve();` is better than what I did?

Answer (score 0):

Steve Tomlin's comment suggested to use `reject` and `resolve`. I after that I managed to make it work as expected. My final code looks like this.

```
let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //1. Trigger on change on page load. This will load dates dropdown.
        $("#id_session_type").trigger('change');
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 500);
    }).then(function(result){
            //2. Select date
            set_date_from_hidden();
            return result;
        }).then(function(result){
            //Trigger on change for the selected date. This will load times dropdown.
            $("#id_date").trigger('change');
            return result;
    });
```

Comment: This does however not wait for the `change` listener. It just always waits half a second.

Comment: @Bergi do you have any other suggestion to make it better? I find promises really hard to grasp.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous operation, so you need promises to make sure the execution sequence.

Comment: I tried what you posted as answer. But It still has the issue that I mentioned in OP.  First `then()` is executed too soon for it to be able to process the dropdown data fetched by an ajax call. How do I address that issue?

Comment: @Newbie You haven't really shared in the question what the event listeners do and what you actually want to wait for